# Logrotate archive old log files which has date extension

Tags: logs, backup, file-copy, logrotate

Everyday a log file is created in my directory, but with time, there tend to be a lot of log files. I want to keep the latest 4 log files in .log format, and compress the rest and copy the compressed files to backup folder. Normally log files would named as follows.

```
application.log <- the latest log 
application.log.2015-04-16
application.log.2015-04-15
application.log.2015-04-14

another_app.log
another_app.log.2015-04-16
another_app.log.2015-04-15
another_app.log.2015-04-14
another_app.log.2015-04-13
```

etc.

I wrote the following script which I included inside logrotate.conf.
It does not work. I don't want to delete any log files. I want only to compress old log files and copy those compressed files to a backup folder.

```
/root/tharidu/log/*.log{
    missingok
    compress
    dateext
    dateformat "YYYY-MM-DD"
    notifempty
    daily
    rotate 4
    postrotate
        cp /root/tharidu/log/*.gz /root/tharidu/backup
    endscript
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any compressed files in your list. Did you forget to type the `.gz` part? Esp. because you explicitly state "Normally zip files would named as following" (although .gz files aren't really "zip" files, they're gzipped files).

Comment: Make sure your syntax is correct and there is no permission issue.

Comment: I have edited question so that it is more clear.

Comment: There is a space missing between the log file pattern and `{`.